# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 for _NTP_Logging

Tags: ios, xcode

First of all there is a lot of question Asked how to solve that compilation Error that seems happening when importing lib/files. Can anyone explain what does it mean by "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" first of all. I imported files for ntp client for iso  (http://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/source/checkout) which worked in its own Xcode project but when i moved to my project and it failed with the following Error and warnings . Any idea ?

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
     "_NTP_Logging", referenced from:
      -[NetAssociation evaluatePacket] in NetAssociation-586077E517B5DC42.o
      -[NetworkClock associationTrue:] in NetworkClock-496336397AA5FC44.o
      -[NetworkClock associationFake:] in NetworkClock-496336397AA5FC44.o
    "_DEFINE_SHARED_INSTANCE_USING_BLOCK", referenced from:
     +[NetworkClock sharedInstance] in NetworkClock-496336397AA5FC44.o
    "_LogInProduction", referenced from:
     -[NetAssociation enable] in NetAssociation-586077E517B5DC42.o
     -[NetAssociation finish] in NetAssociation-586077E517B5DC42.o
     -[NetAssociation onUdpSocketDidClose:] in NetAssociation-586077E517B5DC42.o
     -[NetworkClock createAssociations] in NetworkClock-496336397AA5FC44.o
     -[NetworkClock applicationBack:] in NetworkClock-496336397AA5FC44.o
     -[NetworkClock applicationFore:] in NetworkClock-496336397AA5FC44.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


  Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/SwapViews_3/NetAssociation.h' of type   
 sourcecode.c.h for architecture armv7
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have .h files among .c files to be compiled.
Go to "Build Phases" tab of your target. Then check the "Compile Sources" section and remove the .h files.